# React Native refusing to work with Chart

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I am new to React-Native and I'm developing an app for Android. I've tried out implementing a chart ... i installed the node_module *react-native-chart* from here https://github.com/tomauty/react-native-chart, and I've written the following component, similar to the component provided in the Usage part of the getting started tutorial with the chart.

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import Chart from 'react-native-chart';
import {View,
    Picker,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Navigator,
    TouchableHighlight}
    from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    chart: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
    },
});

const data = [[
    [0, 1],
    [1, 3],
    [3, 7],
    [4, 9],
]];

export default class Chart extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Chart
                    style={styles.chart}
                    data={data}
                    verticalGridStep={5}
                    type="line"
                    showDataPoint={true}
                    color={['#e1cd00']}
                />

                <Button
                    style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'red'}}
                    styleDisabled={{color: 'red'}}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigator.pop()}>
                    Back
                </Button>

            </View>
        )
    }

}
```

Whenever I click on the button from my other component that should open up the Chart component, the app crashes. If I remove the Chart from the render method, the component loads up fine, displaying only the Button

What should I do ?

Comment: Share how errors look like pls

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca I have only included the component, because there is no error provided on the screen ... When I click the button that should fire up my Chart component the application crashes, leaving behind a dialog that says "Unfortunately, AppName has stopped." But if I take out the Chart from the render method, the component gets loaded as it should

Comment: Did you try my answer? Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, I did try it. I got the same thing going on.

Comment: @SimpleFuzz try out my answer below

Answer (score 0):

App crashes, specially in Android, are caused in absence of library files.

> npm install react-native-chart --save

is OK however this is a module that uses native components-not a pure js repo.

You should do a [manual linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html) or use

> rnpm link react-native-chart

Or

> react-native link react-native-chart